# PHP: Most Efficient Way to Track if a User is Online?

Tags: php, tracking, scalable

I'm developing a project of mine with scalability in mind and I've come to a crossroad. On my website I would like to detect if a user is online or not. And I can't quite think of the best way to handle this. The way I was thinking would be something along these lines(in psuedocode):

```
// SQL user table:
user {
  "name": "blah blah",
  "email": "derpy@derpyderp.com",
  "online": false
}
```

So whenever the user logs in I could update his `online` column to `true`. However that would eventually lead to SQL queries happening every time a user logs in and if it happens that I get say, 10 logins per second, well, that's a lot of queries happening. Another way I figured I could do the same thing but in a different table:

```
// Activity table:
activity {
  "user_id": 2,
  "online": true
}
```

For some reason I believe that would lead to less memory consumption because of the separation from the `user` table. However I'm not sure if it would have any actual effect on performance.

So if you could bless me with your insight I would be more then grateful, thank you.

Comment: This seems like premature optimization. I wouldn't worry about it for now. If and when your site starts to get slow, I'm sure you'll be able to identify much more significant bottlenecks than this.

Comment: It is common to run a number of SQL queries everytime a new page is loaded. One additional query will not be noticeable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking it's a common practice to add a column to the users table to store the `lastActivity` time. Anytime the user logs in, or accesses a page, store the current time in that field. If you want to know whether or not they are *online*, see if the last recorded time is within a certain window - say, five minutes. You can query all rows to see how many users are currently online as a result.

I wouldn't be too worried about running queries every few seconds - your server can handle it (assuming these are well-written and not very verbose).

Answer (score 0):

you can use datetime for field type and don't forget to record user IP so you can track time o

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it to work you basically have two options:

Define a timeout after which you consider a user logged out
Use ajax/websockets/whatever to poll user

```
       1: Timeout
```

This is the simpler use case. Every time the user requests a page, you update a timestamp in your database.

To find out how many users are online, you would do a query against this database and do a COUNT of users who have been active in the last N minutes.

This way you will get a relatively accurate idea of how many people are actively using the site at the moment.

```
      2: Constant polling
```

This is a bit more complex to implement due to having to update the server with Ajax. Otherwise it works in a similar fashion to #1.

Whenever a user is on a page, you can keep a websocket open or do ajax requests every N seconds to the server.

This way you can get a pretty good idea of how many people have pages open on your site currently, but if a user leaves the page open in their browser and doesn't do anything, it would still count them as being online.

A slight modification to the idea would be to use a script on the client to monitor mouse movement. If the user doesn't move the mouse on your page for say 10 minutes, you would stop the polling or disconnect the websocket. This would fix the problem of showing users who are idle as being online.